# Custom CalendarView(Hijri)

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview, hijri

My app is about Hijri(Islamic)calendar but default android CalendarView is gregorian!
How can I customize Android Calendar View?!

I need some thing like this:

> [image]

Comment: I found answer: noway to customize to hijri or some thing like that!

Comment: best way: build your own calendar view with text view!

Comment: i am also working on hijri calender,i am using this https://github.com/sahaab/HijriCalendar-master but it does not show proper dates,,can you share code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi visit all given links, hope will help you

1.https://github.com/inteist/android-better-time-picker

2.https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

3.http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html

4.http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/

5.http://abinashandroid.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/how-to-create-custom-calendar-in-android/

6.http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

7.https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

8.https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

when you will visit the following:

https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

For a working implementation of this project see the sample/ folder.

Implement the appropriate `Handler callbacks`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements     DatePickerDialogFragment.DatePickerDialogHandler {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
      }

      @Override
      public void onDialogDateSet(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Do something with your date!
      }
    }
```

Use one of the Builder classes to create a `PickerDialog` with a theme:

```
DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
        .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
        .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment);
dpb.show();
```

also for an another example you can visit

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

and use as follows

To embed the caldroid fragment in your activity, use below code:

```
    CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
t.commit();
```